# karma and CSS files: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve"

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I run `karma start karma.config.js` and I get (slightly edited):

> ERROR in ./Content/ebbMain.css Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'check.png' in 'Content'

This is a CSS file that references images through the URL property. E.g.:

```
background-image: url("my-image.png")
```

I know that these references are correct because they show properly in the web app. At this point, I'm just interested in ignoring/ excluding CSS files from karma. I've been googling for hours and nothing worked. Thans for any pointers.

Comment: Something to [check out](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html). Look for the `included` flag being set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by using the `css-loader` plugin and configuring `webpack` in `karma.config.js`.
Please note that the `url=false` option indicates `css-loader` to ignore the `url` bits in the CSS files, which eventually solved the error.
Please also note that you may need to add more configurations depending on your specific project. Good luck!

```
webpack: {
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        loaders: ['css-loader?url=false']
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```